# PostgreSQL skips WITH query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, cte

Consider this CTE:

```
WITH division_by_zero AS (
  SELECT 1/0
)
SELECT 42
```

It returns 42 instead of raising an error. How can I force PostgreSQL to evaluate the `SELECT 1/0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the main query doesn't reference `division_by_zero` anywhere.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) says:

> [...] PostgreSQL's implementation evaluates only as many rows of a `WITH` query as are actually fetched by the parent query.

That is zero in your case.

If you want the CTE to be executed, you could for example add a `WHERE` condition like

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM division_by_zero)
```

Comment: "Parent query" seems to be `SELECT 42` in this case (the documentation is missing a definition of the term). I have to somehow reference the "child query" (in my case, it's a function call with side effects)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You could use something like `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM division_by_zero)`.